# I have some problem swift core data in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using Core Data in my app. so I try. to implement and dependency injection like this. but I have some error. " Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)". here is a code and debugger picture.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NoteDraftViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var noteTableView: UITableView!

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        noteTableView.dataSource = self            
    }
}
```

.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //3.5 aris video
        //how to context can be created
        let mainContext = createMainContext()

        let fisrtViewContoller = getFirstViewController()
        fisrtViewContoller.managedObjectContext = mainContext

        return true
    }


    func getFirstViewController() -> NoteDraftViewController {
        //Get the window's root view controller (which is navigation controller)
       let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

        // Get the navigation controller's first view controller
        // Cast it to a ShoutOutDraftsViewController and return
        let firstVC = navigationController.viewControllers[0]

        return firstVC as! NoteDraftViewController
    }..........
```

The debugger shows this message:
[image]

Comment: i have swift 5.0 version in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your function as follows, removing the force unwrapping:

```
func getFirstViewController() -> NoteDraftViewController? {
    if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController, 
    let firstVC = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? NoteDraftViewController {
        return firstVC
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
```

And then in your `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let mainContext = createMainContext()

    if let firstViewContoller = getFirstViewController() {
       firstViewContoller.managedObjectContext = mainContext
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Glad to help - I recommend to read up on optionals and how to avoid similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`window?.rootViewController` is not a `UINavigationController` so by force casting it to one, it's crashing. You need to create a navigation controller with a root view controller. try:

```
let rootVC = window?.rootViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
```

Comment: I totally missed the error and was looking at the wrong line. updated my answer

Comment: I updated my code like this 

  let rootVC = (window?.rootViewController)!
  let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
      
but now I have this problem, which I had before.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using iOS 13 window will be nil in appDelegate in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**  so move this to **SceneDelegate** plus your are casting window.rootViewController which is currently nil as! UINavigationController so it's crashing you should first move to sceneDelegate and insert this code

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourControllerObject)
```

Comment: where exactly I add this code "window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourControllerObject)" in sceneDelegate?

Comment: add it to func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)